# cURL get content through user IP

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl

i tried to get content by php in my server using cURL for the url : http://www.t100v.com/apk/V2.php

but it is responding data the " key " value generated by the ip that made the request.

i tried to send the user ip address with the request but did not work
how can the user's IP address be sent with cURL request? Many websites blocked the server IP address to access through cURL.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$externalIpAdress ='1.1.1.1 example' ;
$ID = '1858';
$url = 'https://www.t100v.com/apk/V2.php';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'android_app');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Forwarded-For: $externalIpAdress"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json_a = json_decode($result, true);
$play_url= $json_a['app_version']['play_url'].'?';
$key= $json_a['app_version']['key'].'S54@daE#';
$key2= $json_a['app_version']['key'];
$exp= $json_a['app_version']['exp'];
$token = md5($key.$exp.$ID);

$final= $play_url.'key='.$key2.'&exp='.$exp.'&token='.$token.'&id='.$ID;
echo  $final;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the request to come from the user's IP address then you need to run the code *on the user's computer*.

You can't spoof their IP address and get the response which would be addressed to that IP and not arrive at your computer at all.

Answer (score 1):

simple, have the user install PHP-cli on his own computer (MacOS ship with php from Apple, Windows users can download pre-compiled php-cli here: https://windows.php.net/download/ and all major linux distributions have php in their repositories), and then have the user run the script on his own machine.

- either that, or fetch the final data with your php script too and stream it from your site.